# Python - Print list of objects in a table

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, object

I have a class with several attributes:

```
class Fighter():
    def __init__(self, name = "", gender = "", age = 0, weight = 0, win = 0, loss = 0, ko = 0, date = ""):

        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__win = win
        self.__loss = loss
        self.__ko = ko
        self.__date = date
```

From the user end of my program, an object is created and stored in a list using the following lines in a loop:

```
s = Fighter(name, gender, age, weight, wins, losses, ko, time) 

collection.append(s)
```

I am able to sort this list by a number of attributes, such as name, weight, etc. and that works perfectly. I also have instance methods inside the class that return the value of a specific attribute, such as:

```
def fighter_age(self):
    return str(self.__age)
```

My question is, how do I print this information as an organized table, with a  column for each attribute, such as:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|Fighter Number|Name          |Age |Weight  |Wins|Losses|Date Added   |
|1             |Anderson Silva|39  |185     |33  | 6    |2014-01-17   |
```

Comment: The key issue is finding the correct width of each column: you should prepare your data and do a first loop to find the largest width for each column (with a limit, to avoid extra long strings) and then loop again and print

Comment: If printing is not so important, have you considered exporting in csv or Excel?

Comment: coding tip: avoid __ prefixes, as they lead to 'strange' behaviours (see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for coding style)

Answer (score 0):

Check the duplicate link, and consider doing:

```
import sys
def prt_width(str, width):
    sys.stdout.write('|' + str + ' '*(width-len(str)) + '|')
    sys.stdout.flush()

for fighter in collection:
    prt_width(fighter.number)
    prt_width(fighter.name)
    ...
    prt_width('\n')
```

Note: This would require you to calculate the maximun length of each field in advance (for instance, you need to loop through all names and determain the maximum length of a all names before submitting them for print, or just find a standard value that usually works). This is a manual approach, for some reason i tend to argue for going with manual approaches to learn stuff. Check the duplicate link for good libraries that does the thinking for you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be a bit clever about this, and use some of the functionality having a class gives you, you could store the width of the widest entry for each instance attribute as a class attribute:

```
class Fighter():
    max_name_len = 4 # start with width of header 'Name'
    ...

    def __init__(self, name, ...):
        if len(name) > Fighter.max_name_len :
            Fighter.max_name_len = len(name)
        ...
```

You can update these class attributes each time you create a new `Fighter` or change one of the their attributes (see [`property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) for how to wrap the attributes that might change with checking code). This saves you from needing to loop through `collection` each time you want to build the table.

You could then create an instance method to produce the line entry for each instance:

```
    def table_row(self, num): # note argument for fighter number
        # return string with appropriate widths
```

and a class method to do the headers:

```
    @classmethod
    def table_header(cls):
        # return strings with headers
```

Then when you print out the table, it looks like:

```
print Fighter.table_header()
for num, fighter in enumerate(collection, 1):
    print fighter.table_row(num)
```

Here [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) gives you the number for each `Fighter` in `collection`, starting with `1`, as well as the actual `Fighter` objects.